# Дан массив действительных чисел A[N]. Найти max(a1+a2n, a2+a2n-1,…,an+an+1)

Tags: java, массивы

Задача: Дан массив действительных чисел `A[N]`. Найти `max(a1+a2n, a2+a2n-1,…,an+an+1)`.
Так как я совсем зеленый, пробовал сначала написать прямолинейно:

```
double max = array[0] + array[array.length - 1];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (max < array[i] + array[array.length*2 - 1]);
        max = array[i] + array[array.length * 2 - 1];
    }
```

Но в таком примере я скорее всего получу `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Искал ответ в интернете, и наткнулся на следующую реализацию этого примера:

```
public static int getMaxSum(int[] array) {
    int maxSum = array[0] + array[array.length - 1];
    for (int i = 1; i < array.length / 2; i++) {
        if ((array[i] + array[array.length - i - 1]) > maxSum) {
            maxSum = array[i] + array[array.length - i - 1];
        }

    }
    return maxSum;
}
```

Тут проблема с `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` вроде бы решена. Однако я не совсем понимаю принципа:

- Сокращаем на 2 чтобы не получить исключение?
- Зачем от длины массива отнимать индекс?

Может кто-нибудь объяснить?

Comment: `max(a1+a2n, a2+a2n-1,…,an+an+1)` - что, что?? Если N==n, то откуда в массиве длиной N индексы 2N?

Comment: Приведите примеры входных  данных и результата.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы ответить на Ваши вопросы проще всего будет рассмотреть пример.
Допустим `N=10`. Тогда массив будет иметь вид - `[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10]`. Согласно заданию нам необходимо найти максимальное число из чисел `[a1+a10,a2+a9,a3+a8,a4+a7,a5+a6]`. Учитывая переместительное свойство сложения в вычислении чисел `[a10+a1,a9+a2,a8+a3,a7+a4,a6+a5]` нет смысла. Соотвественно нам достаточно пройти в цикле только половину массива `N/2` и вычислять позицию второго слагаемого основываясь на длине массива - `N-i`.